# AngularJS accessing 'this' within a $http

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Within my AngularJS service I'm trying to call method within the same file within a $http success block and I have to use 'that = this' so I can access it properly.

```
calc_total: (line) ->
  that = this
  $http.get("/item/get_cost?costing_id=" + line.costing_id).then (
    (response) ->
      # If successful set the cost per unit cents
      line.cost_cents = response.data['cost_cents']
      that.accumulated_balance(line) # Update balance
  )
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: This works, but is there a way to pass in 'this' into the http block so that I can access it? I think the 'that = this' code is messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fat arrow `=>` to preserve the `this` from the `calc_total` closure:

```
calc_total: (line) ->
  $http.get("/item/get_cost?costing_id=" + line.costing_id).then (
    (response) =>
      # If successful set the cost per unit cents
      line.cost_cents = response.data['cost_cents']
      this.accumulated_balance(line) # Update balance
  )
```

See [this guide](http://webapplog.com/understanding-fat-arrows-in-coffeescript/) for reference.

The JavaScript ES5 equivalent is

```
function () {}.bind(this);
```

The fat arrow syntax made its way into ES6 as well.